# Laravel adding/finding relationships for relationships

Tags: orm, laravel, relationships, eloquent

How to find relationships for relationships with Eloquent ORM? Currently I have something like this. Simple relationship. I can find Image and it's photographer. Now I need to do something more complex, I need to find also photographers tags.

**dump looks like this**

```
object(Image) {
    ["attributes"] => [],
    ["relationships"] =>
        ["photographer"] =>
            ["attributes"] => [],
            ["relationships"] =>
}
```

**But I need to add tags relationship so It would look like this**

```
object(Image) {
    ["attributes"] => [],
    ["relationships"] =>
        ["photographer"] =>
            ["attributes"] => [],
            ["relationships"] =>
                ["tags"] =>
                    ["attributes"] => [],
                    ["relationships"] =>
}
```

**How is that possible?**

*/Image model*

```
public function photographer()
{
    return $this->belongs_to('Photographer');
}

public function tags()
{
    return $this->has_many_and_belongs_to('Tag', 'tag_relationships');
}
```

*/Controller*

```
$images = Image::with(['photographer'])->order_by('updated_at', 'desc')->get();
```

Comment: Got an answer at IRC. Maybe this will work Image::with(['photographer', 'photographer.tags']), will test it tomorrow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you just use laravel's dot syntax:

```
Image::with(['photographer', 'photographer.tags', 'photographer.tags.categories]) ....
```

Comment: It is - [Eloquent ORM - Eager Loading](http://laravel.com/docs/database/eloquent#eager)